# Javascript won't open filebrowser for Phonegap app correctly - but HTML does

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm new to HTML/Javascript/Jquery, so this question may seem basic. 
But I've found a [filebrowser online](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/file-chooser-dialog-for-phonegap-application/) that I want to use in my app in Phonegap. 
The thing is, the example I've downloaded uses this method to open the filebrowser.

```
<a href="fileBrowser.html"  data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="browseBtn">Browse</a>
```

But I need to use the Javascript to open it, because I only want it when I longpress the button.
But neither of these methods work:

```
window.location.href = ("fileBrowser.html");
window.open("fileBrowser.html");
```

Which I call like this (just to test if it works):

```
<a onclick="test()"  data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="browseBtn">Browse</a>
```

It is supposed to come out like this:

[image: Working version from example]

But unfortunately, it comes out as this, when I use Javascript:
[image: Nonworking, opened with javascript]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you use jQuery Mobile?

Use this:

```
$.mobile.changePage("fileBrowser.html");
```